# disable ?debug_assets=1 without losing asset pipeline, for rails app in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

A very simple question: how to disable `?debug_assets=1` for rails app in production?

Its not as simple as-is though, who knows a way to have this disable but still keep the sprockets asset pipeline feature in rails 3.2.x app be maintained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
# in config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.allow_debugging = false
```